# My internet is slow but only on one computer

Tags: windows-10, internet, connection

My internet is slow but only on one computer, it's so slow it can't load YouTube videos and go on some sites. I have looked everywhere on the internet to find a solution, from updating drivers, checking for malware to reinstalling chrome, running "ping www.google.com" in command prompt. My computer's OS is the newest version of Windows 10. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Edit:  If it helps my ping is 5ms, download speeds are at 14.95, upload speeds are at 0.76mbps, odd because another computer connected to ethernet is getting 46mbps downloads and 4mbps uploads.

Edit: I found out that I may need to reset Windows 10 as it may be corrupted. I however won't do this until I am sure that Windows is corrupted.

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer this and can only guess. Did you [search the site](https://superuser.com/search?q=is%3Aq+internet+slow)?

Comment: Yes I did, nothing, literally nothing worked.

Comment: What other info do you need?

Comment: How does your device connect to the Internet? What does MTR/winmtr (or ping and trace route) show? Have you checked the network cable?

Comment: Connects using an ethernet cable, don't know what I'm doing with ping and tracert, the cable is ok, problem persists with wifi.

Comment: Try running TCP/IP Reset:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer
If this does not work, try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link before resetting Windows

Comment: Try getting Windows to troubleshoot your network adapters and see if it identifies any problems. I had a very similar issue recently that turned out to be a random DNS problem on my laptop. Windows diagnosed and fixed it itself in 10 seconds when I clicked on `Troubleshoot`.

Comment: The troubleshooter didn't find anything, but I'll try repairing windows.